# How to get the top rated products in the following case?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm using **Django==3.2** and **Django-rest-framework==3.12.4** . I have  two modals with following names **Product** and **ProductRating**.

As you can see below:

```
class Product(models.Model):


   
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='userprofile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    name = models.CharField(("name"), max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(_("price"),default=0)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(_("Create time"), default=timezone.now)




class ProductRating(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_("user"), on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, verbose_name=_("product"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stars = models.IntegerField(_("stars"),default=0)
    is_remove = models.BooleanField(_("is_remove"),default=False)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(_("Create time"), default=timezone.now)
```

Now I want to get the top rated products. According to the average rating of each product. the product that has highest rating and most count of reviews should appear first in the query list.
I have tried the following thing but that just gave me those products who has any rating element.
as you can see below.

```
def get_all_top_rated_projects(self):
        query = self.filter(productrating__isnull=False)
        print( query[0].productrating.object.all())
```

I know its quite tricky case. I have tried to do it by myself. But i'm unable to do that. Anyone expert You can help and pull me out from this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Avg` database function

```py
from django.db.models import Avg, Q

Product.objects.annotate(avg_rate=Avg("product__stars", filter=Q(product__is_remove=False))).order_by("avg_rate")
```

Comment: there is no field avg_rate

Comment: Is this an error message? We added avg_rate field via annotate